# TextMesh Pro errors running Unity in Debian 10 GNU/Linux

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, gnu

I started to try Unity GNU/Linux version. I got a project in my job that was written in Unity Editor version 5.6.6f2 for Windows. I could open the project in Unity Editor version 2019.3.8f1 after Unit Hub converting it for this newer version.

I'm getting a series of building errors now. And many of them are related to TextMesh Pro Asset in scripts generated during the building. Like

```
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAsset.cs(405,34): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.TextCore.FaceInfo' to 'TMPro.FaceInfo'
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAssetUtilities.cs(302,82): error CS1061: 'FaceInfo' does not contain a definition for 'pointSize' and no accessible extension method 'pointSize' accepting a first argument of type 'FaceInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAssetUtilities.cs(344,82): error CS1061: 'FaceInfo' does not contain a definition for 'pointSize' and no accessible extension method 'pointSize' accepting a first argument of type 'FaceInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAsset.cs(612,84): error CS1061: 'FaceInfo' does not contain a definition for 'tabWidth' and no accessible extension method 'tabWidth' accepting a first argument of type 'FaceInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAsset.cs(649,28): error CS1061: 'FaceInfo' does not contain a definition for 'capLine' and no accessible extension method 'capLine' accepting a first argument of type 'FaceInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAsset.cs(652,28): error CS1061: 'FaceInfo' does not contain a definition for 'capLine' and no accessible extension method 'capLine' accepting a first argument of type 'FaceInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

There's a log file, `Logs/Packages-Update.log`, that I suppose is related to the updates made when converting the project from 5.6.6f2 version to 2019.3.8f1 version. The content of that file is

```
Packages were changed.
Update Mode: resetToDefaultDependencies

The following packages were added:
  com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16
  com.unity.ide.rider@1.1.4
  com.unity.ide.vscode@1.1.4
  com.unity.modules.ai@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.androidjni@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.animation@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.assetbundle@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.audio@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.cloth@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.director@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.imageconversion@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.imgui@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.jsonserialize@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.particlesystem@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.physics@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.physics2d@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.screencapture@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.terrain@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.terrainphysics@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.tilemap@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.ui@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.uielements@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.umbra@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unityanalytics@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.vehicles@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.video@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.vr@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.wind@1.0.0
  com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0
  com.unity.test-framework@1.1.13
  com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1
  com.unity.timeline@1.2.14
  com.unity.ugui@1.0.0
```

See the `com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1` line in that.

I'm totally new to Unity and I don't use Windows. So I'm wondering if that have something related to C# scripting (like libraries that I have to install in Debian to properly compile a project), or if the errors are specific to TextMesh Pro asset etc.

If anyone have had this type of error or can give me tips to make Unity works in a Debian GNU/Linux environment...

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete the old version of TextMesh Pro in the Asset folder
2. Reopen Project
3. Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import TMP essentials
4. Window -> TextMeshPro -> Project Files GUID Remapping Tool.
5. Scan & Save.

This will update the project and fix all missing TMP scripts.